# File disappeared after move

Tags: windows, windows-8, shell-script

I have used the following command hoping to move pdf files from

```
\\netdrive\F1\F2\Source\
```

to another folder

```
 \\netdrive\F3\F4\Des\
```

Command:

```
PushD "\\netdrive\F1\F2\Source\" &&(forfiles /m *.pdf /C "cmd /c move @file ..\..\..\F3\F4\Des") & popd
```

When I run it in the CMD it shows x file(s) moved. And they do get disappeared from my source folder, but I can't find any of them in my destination folder...

So my question is where can I find these files now?

PS: I had successfully moved file to

```
\\netdrive\F1\F2\Source\sub\
```

using:

```
PushD "\\netdrive\F1\F2\Source\" &&(forfiles /m *.pdf /C "cmd /c move @file .\sub") & popd
```

Comment: Try it again with `echo` before the `move` command so you can see exactly what it is doing ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: something like: `"....... cmd /c echo move @file ..\..\..\F3\F4\Des\") & popd` ?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: @DavidPostill, it prints out: `move filename ..\..\..\F3\F4\Des"`  looks like there is an extra `"` in the end...  but it shouldn't mater, as `move filename .\sub"` still work.

Comment: BTW, if this is a new script, you really should be looking at using Powershell.

Comment: @Zoredache, I was trying to use it in a scheduled task. Will check Powershell.

Comment: @Zoredache, much easier using Powershell. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you figure this out?  Since your example is somewhat obfuscated, it isn't clear to me what is the `\\server\share`, and what is a sub-folder of the share   I don't think you can use relative paths like `..\..\` to cross into another share.  But it almost seems like you tried to do that.

I would guess you would have gotten the correct results if you had used the absolute path for the destination instead.

What I would be tempted to do is figure out what the physical path for `\\netdrive\F1` share is on the server, then look in `%physpath\..\F3\F4\Des\`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But how can I get the absolute path using the script?

Comment: And I can definitely access "\\netdrive\F3\F4\Des\" by using "\\netdrive\F1\F2\Source\..\..\..\F3\F4\Des\" in windows explorer.